# Task scheduler: run 1 tasks 4 times a day

Tags: scheduled-tasks

It seems like I have to add `4 tasks` to run the same job at `9am, 11am, 2pm, and 4pm`. Is there a way to run the same job `4 times with 1 task`?

If yes, how do I configure that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

(I'll assume you are using Win 7). In the Create Task dialog, click the Triggers tab. Then click the New button. In the New Trigger dialog, you will see an Advanced Settings section. It has a Repeat Task area. You can put a checkmark in that box and choose a preset value or type your own---e.g. 4 hours or 45 minutes.

Comment: It's on Win 2008. I do see trigger and Added one trigger but it does have repeated task and i put every 2 hours. But I only need to run it 4 times a day. I guess I can put 6 hours under "for a duration of". What do you suggest?

Comment: You can change your value of every 2 to every 6 (hours). That will effectively run your task 4 times in one 24 hour period.

Comment: @Thank you aendenne. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Great answer @aendenne, I was stumped but your answer showed me how embarrassingly simple it really was. I had no idea the frequency box was editable. I thought I was limited to the presets. oops

Answer (score 27):

It looks like you can add mulitple triggers for a task setting a different time for each trigger.  Go back to your task, right click and pick properties.  On the "Triggers" tab you can add more tirggers.

Comment: Perfect, that's the most elegant solution.

Comment: Awesome! I have never realized this.

Comment: Is this possible to set multiple triggers using cmd SCHTASKS?

Answer (score 6):

You can also just type "6 hours" in the drop-down.  Not intuitive, but it works.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/74a10148-36c9-432b-be1c-9833d4cbfd86/task-scheduler-repeat-task-every-is-not-granular-enough?forum=winserverManagement

Comment: Multiple Triggers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238085/2440976) seems more intuitive and easier to view& track.